# remove action Woocommerce issue in child theme

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

With Woocommerce, I am using [sober](https://themeforest.net/item/sober-woocommerce-wordpress-theme/18332889) theme and I am trying to override some of theme's default functions, but things are not working as I expect.

For instance, I wrote below block in my child theme `functions.php`:

```
function remove_parent_theme_function() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary',
                   'woocommerce_template_single_rating', 15 );
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'remove_parent_theme_function');
```

I expected from above code block to remove the rating section from my product page, but it is not.

What should I do to override parent theme actions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template function `woocommerce_template_single_rating` is hooked with a priority of **`10`**  (and not **`15`**)… Try the following instead:

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'remove_single_rating', 2 );
function remove_single_rating() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_rating', 10 );
}
```

This code goes on function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). It should works.

---

Or if your main parent theme is making made some changes on this with a priority of `15`, use:

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'remove_single_rating', 2 );
function remove_single_rating() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_rating', 15 );
}
```

Or

```
add_action('init', 'remove_single_rating', 2 );
function remove_single_rating() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_rating', 15 );
}
```